# What does the "exit code 10" mean in C?

Tags: c

I am using Sublime to program in C but when the code is compiled it keeps returning `[Finished in 1.1s with exit code 10]`. What does that mean? What is going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: Depends on the program.

Comment: I put the piece of code I'm using. It's really simple!

Comment: `void main()` is non-standard. Use `int main()`

Comment: As @bolov implies, in this case it means your program invokes undefined behavior. Google `C main return value` and you'll answer yourself.

Comment: Thank you, guys!!! I really appreciate those answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

main( ) does not take void as a return type.In C programming language we use int as a return type of main .Exit codes are nothing but Windows System Error Codes .I think you are using windows Operating system and for windows Operating system

> exit code 10  means :The environment is incorrect.

May be your installation process was not correct .
Reinstall it and run the program .

Comment: Technically, the `return 0;` statement is implicit as per the C Standard C99 and later. But the Microsoft C compiler is not C99 compliant...